# How to send Image to amazon s3 server in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-s3, uiimage

I am using below code to send image from gallery to amazon server in ios but it is not successful. May i know the format in which it need to send and do i need to pass just the file name or the entire path of the image?

Thanks.

```
NSDictionary *headers = @{ @"content-type": @"multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW",
                           @"x-access-token": @"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1c2UxOTAiLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3d3dy5oY3VlLmNvIiwicGVybWlzc2lvbnMiOiJhdXRoZW50aWNhdGVkIiwidXNlcmlkIjpudWxsLCJpYXQiOjE0ODYyMDczNDB9.ewu2QtoHl1kBSrM1y6yL9Jr58kiGmhCsy2YWoFrE2OU",
                           @"cache-control": @"no-cache",
                            };
NSArray *parameters = @[ @{ @"name": @"username", @"fileName": localFilePath} ];
NSString *boundary = @"----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW";

NSError *error;
NSMutableString *body = [NSMutableString string];
for (NSDictionary *param in parameters) {
    [body appendFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary];
    if (param[@"fileName"]) {
        [body appendFormat:@"Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", param[@"name"], param[@"fileName"]];
        [body appendFormat:@"Content-Type: %@\r\n\r\n", param[@"contentType"]];
        [body appendFormat:@"%@", [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:param[@"fileName"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error]];
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }
    } else {
        [body appendFormat:@"Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param[@"name"]];
        [body appendFormat:@"%@", param[@"value"]];
    }
}
[body appendFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary];
NSData *postData = [body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://zambalauploaddev.ap-southeast-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/upload"]
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:10.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                            completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                if (error) {
                                                    NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                                } else {
                                                    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
                                                    NSLog(@"%@", httpResponse);

                                                    NSDictionary * responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
                                                    NSLog(@"Reponse Dict:%@",responseDict);
                                                }
                                            }];
[dataTask resume];
```

Comment: you have to send file data(NSData).

Comment: [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", @"abc",@"image.jpeg"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: %@\r\n\r\n", mimetype] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:data];//here data is nsdata of your image and NSString *mimetype  = @"image/jpeg";

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `POST` with all of its multipart/form-data complexity, when you could instead simply `PUT` the raw binary image contents?

Comment: best way to use afnetworking for uploading image